# How to get DateRangePicker control value in ASP.NET (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker, datetimepicker

When add (runat="server"), i can get control name "txtDate" but it diskplay like text input.
When without runat="server", control working but i can't get control name to get value.

```
 <input type="text" name="daterange" id="txtDate" runat="server" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015"/>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker();});
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = txtDate.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please include the script that make the textbox as a date-time picker

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469280/asp-net-datetime-picker

Comment: @Null asp:textbox not working :(

Comment: @un-lucky  i was updated the question

Comment: @Azola Date Ranger Picker not Datetime Picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have given the `runat="server"` the accessible id of that particular control from the script will change with respect to the page name/masterpage name if any. so that you have to access them Like the following in script:

```
 $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").daterangepicker();});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this :**

```
 <input type="text" name="daterange" id="txtDate" runat="server" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015"/>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>").daterangepicker();});
</script>
```

Comment: is it needed to change as `asp:Textbox` why not an `input`?

Comment: @un-lucky You are absolutely right, `JS` will not care if you'r using an `ASP Textbox` or `input` , ill edit my answer

Comment: @un-lucky i'm fairly new to programming, this kinda situation helps me a lot to improve my knowledge. Thanks :)

Comment: @un-lucky To keep consistency I would use `TextBox` instead of mixing HTML and ASP controls